# Asp.net Web Forms Event not fired in custom control from a nested control

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, custom-controls

I have a custom control that inherit a GridView.
I have wrote one more class that inherit a BoundField to create a column that display an image into a ButtonClick control.
This "image column" raise an event when I click over it.
In the first GridView Custom control, I have bound the event of the "image column click". It is never fired.

Image column code:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using WebControls.Infrastructure;

namespace WebControls
{

    public class DataSearchGridImageColumn : BoundField
    {

        public event StringDelegate ImageClicked;

        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)ViewState["ImageUrl"] ?? string.Empty;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["ImageUrl"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void InitializeDataCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlRowState rowState)
        {
            var img = new ImageButton
            {
                ID = "ImgSelectRecord",
                ImageUrl = ImageUrl,

            };
            cell.Controls.Add(img);

            img.Click += ImgClick;

        }

        void ImgClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            var img = sender as ImageButton;

            if (img == null) return;

            var row = (GridViewRow)img.NamingContainer;

            if (row == null) return;

            // get the id
            var id = row.Cells[1].Text;


            // raise an event
            OnClick(id);

        }

        protected virtual void OnClick(string id)
        {
            if (ImageClicked != null)
            {
                ImageClicked(this, id);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Data view custom control code where i bind the event:

```
protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
{
    // create a new page because the Page object is null in this context
    var pg = new Page();

    var selectionColumn = new DataSearchGridImageColumn
    {
        ImageUrl = string.Format(
            "url({0})",
            pg.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(GetType(), "WebControls.Images.search.png"))
    };


    Columns.Clear();
    Columns.Add(selectionColumn);
    Columns.Add(CreateColumn(ValueFieldName, ValueFieldName));
    Columns.Add(CreateColumn(TextFieldName, TextFieldName));

    AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    selectionColumn.ImageClicked += SelectionColumnImageClicked;

    base.OnDataBinding(e);

}

void SelectionColumnImageClicked(object sender, string value)
{
    if (RowSelected != null)

        RowSelected(this, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it seems that the event in your parent control fires, but not for those in child controls, right?

Take a look at this [site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1165320.aspx?Nested%20Custom%20Controls%20Events%20not%20firing%20)...

Comment: I found a solution inside your link. Overriding the OnBubbleEvent method in the main control I get the object that raise the click. Thanks.